# How does the code below give the same outcome as the code that follows it. I am trying to understand recursion

Tags: recursion

```
function multiply(arr, n) {

    let product = 1;

    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      product *= arr[i];
    }

    return product;
  }
```

A section in the course of freecode-camp states that the code above gives the same outcome as the code below; Im trying to wrap my head around this, somebody please help me with this;

Lets assume that we use an array of 1,2,3,4,5 and n of 5.

`multiply(arr, n) == multiply(arr, n - 1) * arr[n - 1]`

Comment: Which one can you explain and which one can't you?  For the one you can't fully explain, what *can* you explain about it?

Comment: Note that the second version is incomplete (which might be part of the difficulty).

Comment: The second part is what I cant understand

Comment: What *do* you understand about it?

Comment: I understand that the return of the code left of the equation is supposed to equal the return of the right code. But breaking it down with an array example of 1 to 5, and the n number of 5, I get the first product of 1 which is not the same as the return for 2nd part of code.

Comment: Are you saying for the sample provided the first code returns 1?

Comment: No the first outcome in the set of (1, 2, 6, 24, 120). The second part of code does not return 1. Unless im comparing apples to oranges, or maybe just the whole approach is wrong.

Comment: Okay, I think I don't understand the right side of the code,

Answer (score 0):

The top (iterative) code returns the product of the elements of the array.

What the second one does can be seen by repeated substitution:

```
multiply(arr, 5) == multiply(arr, 5 - 1) * arr[5 - 1]
                 == multiply(arr, 4) * arr[4]
                 == (multiply(arr, 4 - 1) * arr[4 - 1]) * arr[4]
                 == multiply(arr, 3) * arr[3] * arr[4]
                 == (multiply(arr, 3 - 1) * arr[3 - 1]) * arr[3] * arr[4]
                 == multiply(arr, 2) * arr[2] * arr[3] * arr[4]
                 == (multiply(arr, 2 - 1) * arr[2 - 1]) * arr[2] * arr[3] * arr[4]
                 == multiply(arr, 1) * arr[1] * arr[2] * arr[3] * arr[4]
                 == (multiply(arr, 1 - 1) * arr[1 - 1]) * arr[2] * arr[3] * arr[4]
                 == multiply(arr, 0) * arr[0] * arr[1] * arr[2] * arr[3] * arr[4]
```

at which point the process should stop with `multiply(arr,0)` returning 1, but your definition left out that part.